# Для чего нужны контролеры и вью при создания API REST API?

Tags: php, .net, rest

Для чего нужны контролеры и вью при создании REST API?

Или я что то путаю?

Answer (score 1):

Для классического REST вьюшки не нужны, насколько я знаю. Сервер REST возвращает данные в xml, json и т.п. Контроллеры могут использоваться для бизнес-логики REST сервера.

Comment: Чисто технически json-преобразование и будет единственной вьюшкой. Контроллеры не должны использоваться для бизнес-логики, это не их задача.

Comment: Json не требует представления, он выводиться строкой. Такие технологии, как xml поддерживаются почти всеми браузерами, поэтому он тоже ничего не требует на стороне клиента.

Comment: де-факто view преобразует данные - во внутреннем представлении языка - в некоторый вывод. Строка - это и есть этот вывод, т.е., несмотря на то, что это совсем не стандартный шаблонизатор, преобразование все-таки производится - я вот про это.